# Field is not a valid field of the entity - DoctrineEncryptBundle Symfony

Tags: php, forms, symfony, encryption, doctrine-orm

I have a registration form in my application and I want to encrypt the data using the vmelnik-ukraine/DoctrineEncryptBundle for Symfony.
The registration form is from the FOSUserBundle.

I've configured and installed the bundle and imported the @Encrypted annotation in the Entity like this:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use VMelnik\DoctrineEncryptBundle\Configuration\Encrypted;

    /**
    * Developer
    *
    * @ORM\Entity
    * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
    */
    class Developer extends BaseUser
    {
       ...

       /**
        * @var string
        * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=255)
        * @Encrypted
        * @Assert\Length(
        *      min = 2,
        *      max = 50,
        *      minMessage = "profile.register.notification.name.too-short",
        *      maxMessage = "profile.register.notification.name.too-long"
        * )
        */
       private $firstname;
```

But now, when the form is submitted, I get the following error:

```
Field "firstname" is not a valid field of the entity "AppBundle\Entity\Developer" in PreUpdateEventArgs.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think since firstName is defined in BaseUser by FOSUser there might be a confusion between yours and theirs

Comment: I checked and firstName is not defined in User. So that's not the problem. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Maybe it should be protected not private? I'm just guessing out of the blue here

Answer (score 2):

I'm using [a noticeably similar extension](https://github.com/reprovinci/doctrine-encrypt) for Doctrine/Zend and I encountered the same problem. I noticed it happened whenever:

1. I marked a field @Encrypted (e.g. `names`)
2. I left the unencrypted value in the database (e.g. `bob`)
3. I wrote to that table row without changing the unencrypted value (e.g. `(id, bob, x, y, z)`)

I traced the problem to the source code for DoctrineEncryptSubscriber.php (which is the same in vmelnik-ukraine/DoctrineEncryptBundle) here:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args) {
    $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($args->getEntity());
    $properties = $reflectionClass->getProperties();
    foreach ($properties as $refProperty) {
        if ($this->annReader->getPropertyAnnotation($refProperty, self::ENCRYPTED_ANN_NAME)) {
            $propName = $refProperty->getName();
            $args->setNewValue($propName, $this->encryptor->encrypt($args->getNewValue($propName))); // this line is the problem
        }
    }
}
```

`$args->setNewValue(...)` calls `assertValidField($field)`, which checks if the @Encrypted field is in the `entityChangeSet`... which it's not because I didn't make any changes to it. So it throws an exception. And this doesn't happen when the value in the database is already encrypted because then `entityChangeset` has the encrypted value for the old value and the plaintext for the new value.

The patch I'm using is to only call `setNewValue()` when we've actually changed the field, as in here:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $args)
{
    $reflectionClass = new ReflectionClass($args->getEntity());
    $properties = $reflectionClass->getProperties();
    foreach ($properties as $refProperty) {
        if ($this->annReader->getPropertyAnnotation($refProperty, self::ENCRYPTED_ANN_NAME)) {
            $propName = $refProperty->getName();
            if ($args->hasChangedField($propName)) {
                $args->setNewValue($propName, $this->encryptor->encrypt($args->getNewValue($propName)));
            }
        }
    }
}
```